# Nested ng-repeat on same element without flattening original data source

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to generate table rows for the following object

```
$scope.things = [{
    name: 'Bob',
    otherThings: [{
        foo: 'hello'
    },{
        foo: 'bye'
    }]
},{
    name: 'Sid',
    otherThings: [{
        foo: 'cake'
    },{
        foo: 'fish'
    }]
}];
```

The ng-repeat expression I have gone with is:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <tr ng-repeat="otherThing in thing.otherThings">
        <td>{{thing.name}}</td>
        <td>{{otherThing.foo}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This generates multiple tbody elements, one per parent item in my object:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>bye</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Sid</td>
        <td>cake</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sid</td>
        <td>fish</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to avoid multiple tbody elements, but I know in order to access both parent and child items, I will have to nest the ng-repeat's.

I could flatten the original object so that the parent information is duplicated for each child, but I want to avoid this if possible and use the data structure as is.

Are there any special uses of ng-repeat, e.g. multiple expressions that could be used on one ng-repeat to give access to both parent and child items in each iteration?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The reason I want to avoid multiple tbody elements is because I have a css selector for alternate row shading:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: $theme-list-alt;
  }
```

If each parent only had one child item they would all get coloured the same, whereas I want alternate row colours across throughout.

**Update 2**

I wondered whether using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end could help me here, so I tried with the following [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tGkwBuPVbDpePNfBcx9Q?p=preview)

This doesnt give me a row per child, e.g:

```
Bob hello
Bob bye
Sid cake
Sid fish
```

I can see why, just not sure how I can achieve this.

Comment: Use ng-repeat on `<tr>` not on `<tbody>`

Comment: I already am in my example

Comment: but one is on `tbody` I meant that also on `tr`

Comment: I want to avoid multiple tbody elements >> why?

Comment: @mindparse, can you please see my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="thing in things"> 
     <td>{{thing.name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="otherThing in thing.otherThings">{{otherThing.foo}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: 'Try this'... why? what have you done? what was the problem?

Comment: This does not give the desired output I am looking for. I want one row per child item, but the contents of the row should use both parent and child item properties

Comment: Sorry, I thought you answer was what I needed but turns out not. I have added a plunkr to my original post which should demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve, see my second update